# How to deploy laravel in subdirectory for windows server return 404

Tags: php, laravel, windows, deployment, server

I tried to deploy my laravel project in a subdirectory in windows server, but it's always returns 404 Not Found.
Any ideas why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can create a .htaccess file in root that includes:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
  </IfModule>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
  RewriteRule ^ ^$1 [N]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (\.\w+$) [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^ server.php
</IfModule>
```

**EDITED**:
Another way is creation of a virtual host in apache.
you can googling for how to. and there are so many tutorials for that.
But you must be careful the destination uri must be /public folder.

Comment: Does .htaccess works for windows server?

Comment: yes it works but you need must have apache on server, then it will work fine.

Comment: But it's not working, can you provide me with the same code but for web.config?

Comment: .htaccess file overwrite rules for apache webserver. so you can not do such an action in the place like web.config and so on.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:**

Inside your project **add or replace** `.htaccess` file with above code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

 RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule ^ ^$1 [N]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (\.\w+$) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ server.php

</IfModule>
```

**Step 2:**

Now in your project inside public folder **add or replace** `.htaccess` file with above code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

**Step 3:**

After this you can directly call you project with subdirectory name

Comment: Does .htaccess works for the windows server?